# Scheduled sms not working (Code attached)

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

//ScheduleActivity.java//
package com.example.sked;

import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlarmManager;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.DatePicker;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TimePicker;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScheduleActivity extends Activity
{
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

    final int year_set=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month_set=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day_set=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    final int hr_set=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    final int min_set=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    final   DatePicker dp_c = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    final   TimePicker tp_c = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

    dp_c.updateDate(year_set, month_set, day_set); //Setting current date in date picker //

    tp_c.setCurrentHour(hr_set);  //Setting current time in time picker //
    tp_c.setCurrentMinute(min_set);


    //For Scheduling a message//
    final Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_message);
    {
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {


        // Processing the input values from the user//  
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reci_number);
        final String phno= text .getText().toString();

        EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
        final String msg= text1.getText().toString();

        if(phno.length()==10)//Checking length of the mobile number//
        {
        if(msg.length()<=160 && msg.length()>0) //Checking length of the message//
        {


        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);//Getting selected date values// 
        int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = dp.getMonth() + 1;
        int year = dp.getYear();

        TimePicker tp=(TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);//Getting selected time values//
        int hours= tp.getCurrentHour();
        int minutes= tp.getCurrentMinute();


        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();//Getting Current date values//

        final int year_curr=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int month_curr=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day_curr=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        final int hr_curr=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);//Getting Current time values//
        final int min_curr=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        int year_act=year-year_curr;
        int mon_act=month-month_curr;
        int day_act=day-day_curr;
        int hr_act=hours-hr_curr;
        int min_act=minutes-min_curr;

        int diff=year_act+mon_act+day_act+hr_act+min_act;

            if (diff>=0)//Checking if its the future date//
            {


                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsNumber", phno);
                bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsText", msg);
                myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ScheduleActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);//Sending intent to Alarm class//


            int year_act_indays=year_act*365;
            long year_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(year_act_indays, TimeUnit.DAYS);


            int mon_act_indays=mon_act*30;
            long mon_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(mon_act_indays, TimeUnit.DAYS);


            long day_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(day_act, TimeUnit.DAYS);


            long hr_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(hr_act, TimeUnit.HOURS);


            long min_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(min_act, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


            long elapsedtimer_act= year_act_mil+mon_act_mil+day_act_mil+hr_act_mil+min_act_mil;

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,elapsedtimer_act, pendingIntent);

            final AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScheduleActivity.this, 0);

            //set  the dialog  
            dlgAlert.setMessage("Message successfully scheduled at the specified time & date");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Success");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();

            //Reseting the fields//
            EditText text_r = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reci_number);
            ((EditText)text_r).setText("");

            EditText text_m = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
            ((EditText)text_m).setText("");

            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please check the entered date...And enter future time. ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }  

        else
        {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Message too long or too short .... cannot send ... :( ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
        else
        {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Check the number Entered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }


    }

    );



    }



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.schedule, menu);


   // menu.add("Reset");

    return true;
}
```

}

//MyAlarmService.java//

```
package com.example.sked;
```

import android.app.Service;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.IBinder;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;

public class MyAlarmService extends Service 
{

```
String smsNumberToSend, smsTextToSend;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    smsNumberToSend = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("extraSmsNumber");
    smsTextToSend = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("extraSmsText");

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumberToSend, null, smsTextToSend, null, null);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a BroadcastReceiver to schedule events with AlarmManager. Extend BroadcastReceiver and override the onReceive() method, then your device will wakeup for the time required to complete that method. This will let you send your SMS or start a service.

```
class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        //YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Notice that the Wakelock which keeps the device active will only last for the whole onReceive method, so if you start a service or an activity they may not execute all their code before the device goes back to sleep.

In this case the pendingIntent has to be created using "getBroadcast" instead of "getService".

Comment: i have done the changes u said .. but the message is not being sent .. please help ... and the SMS permission's are also set.